# Entity Framework table with one entry

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I have a *MySQL* table with one row. It is *read only*. I've tried to use *DbSet* in *DbContext* but it isn't working.

Table example:

[image: Entry example]

I've created an entity:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeEntity: Entity
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Revision.
  /// </summary>
  public string Revision { get; }
}
```

How should I define *SomeEntity* in **DbContext** class if I have only one record without any *primary key*?

Comment: Do you need to actually model this in Entity Framework?

Comment: I would just use dapper to grab this value out, I don't really see any point in having Entity Framework knowing about it

Comment: For now I need just get the data.

Comment: @CallumLinington Should I make just a query?

Comment: Yeah I would, just do `new DbContext().Database.Query<SomeEntity>().ToListAsync()` something around that

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks!